# RegisterForDispose not called when using HttpSelfHostServer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I am implementing a custom `IHttpControllerActivator` that manages my controller's dependencies using [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

To [release](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasepattern/) my dependencies  I provide to the [`RegisterForDispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969063(v=vs.118).aspx) method a `Release` adapter.

(This strategy is well-known and documented [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI/+)).

```
public class CompositionRoot : IHttpControllerActivator
{    
    public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
        Type controllerType)
    {
        // I removed the Raven IDocumentStore singleton code brevity
        IDocumentSession session = ...

        request.RegisterForDispose(new Release(() =>
        {
            // When the request is over, commit the UoW and clean up.
            session.SaveChanges();
            session.Dispose();
        }));

        var controller = new PollController(session);
        return controller;
    }

    private class Release : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Action _release;

        public Release(Action release)
        {
            _release = release;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _release.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this application via Visual Studio and interact with the API using Fiddler, the `Dispose` method is invoked and all is well.

However, when I run this application using the `HttpSelfHostServer` for the purposes of my boundary tests, the `Dispose` method is never invoked and therefore `SaveChanges` is never invoked - this causes imminent problems.

Could it be that the `DisposeRequestResources` method is not being invoked? I found this [issue](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/56) but has since been closed.

In my boundary test project I use the following factory method to create the `HttpClient`:

```
public static HttpClient Create()
{
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:43594");
    var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
    new Bootstrap().Configure(config);
    var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);

    var client = new HttpClient(server);
    try
    {
        client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
        return client;
    }
    catch
    {
        client.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

I then issue requests against the server and assert against the response.

How can I ensure that the dependency is released when using `HttpSelfHostServer`?